# CartThrob v2.3.2 - How to set up free shipping on orders over £x after any discount has been subtracted?

Tags: ee2, cartthrob, shipping, discounts, coupon-code

I'm using CartThrob v2.3.2 on a site where the client would like to have free shipping on orders over £50 which is easily setup in the shipping options.

However, when a customer uses a coupon code or discount it can bring the order total below £50 but the shipping remains free.

So how can I set it up so that the free shipping is only applied after any discounts have been subtracted from the order total?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be with a custom shipping plugin. You can copy the existing one and update the logic to look for the post-discount total.

1. Copy `Cartthrob_discount_free_shipping_over_x.php`and call it `Cartthrob_discount_free_shipping_over_x_after_discount.php`.
2. Rename `Cartthrob_discount_free_shipping_over_x` class to `Cartthrob_discount_free_shipping_over_x_after_discount`.
3. Change `$title` to `Free Shipping Over X After Discount`.

Then, change the following code:

```
if ($this->core->cart->subtotal() >= $this->core->sanitize_number($this->plugin_settings('order_over')))
```

to

```
if (($this->core->cart->subtotal() - $this->core->cart->discount()) >= $this->core->sanitize_number($this->plugin_settings('order_over')))
```

Feel free to [let us know if you need help with that](https://www.cartthrob.com/support/index.php?pg=request)!

Comment: Thanks Matt, is there any other way of doing it without having to create a custom plugin?

Comment: @Wes doing that is best, and I've now added better instructions for it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed reply Matt, that's very helpful. Sorry one more thing, we are using the shipping plugin 'By Location - Price Threshold' as the client sells to other countries on occasion.  Forgive my lack of understanding here (I have played around with the shipping plugins before), but once I have created this new shipping plugin how can I use it alongside the location plugin above?

Comment: @Wes in this case, you'd want to make a single custom shipping plugin that combines the features of both, with the exact logic you want (location threshold and post-discount free shipping). You could start by copying "By Location - Price Threshold" and adding the discount logic from above. Feel free to get in touch if you'd like us to help!